# How do I use multiprocessing to extract links from webpages with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-multiprocessing

I have a list of links and I create a Beautiful Soup object for each link and scrape all the links within paragraph tags from the page. Because I have hundreds of links I'd like to scrape from, a single process would take more time than I'd like so multiprocessing seems to be the ideal solution.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

urls = ['https://hbr.org/2011/05/the-case-for-executive-assistants','https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3450-when-culture-turns-into-policy']

def collect_links(urls):

    extracted_urls = []
    bsoup_objects = []
    p_tags = [] #store language between paragraph tags in each beautiful soup object

    workers = 4 
    processes = [] 
    links = Queue() #store links extracted from urls variable
    web_connection = Queue() #store beautiful soup objects that are created for each url in urls variable 

    #dump each url from urls variable into links Queue for all processes to use
    for url in urls:
        links.put(url)

    for w in xrange(workers):
        p = Process(target = create_bsoup_object, args = (links, web_connection)) 
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
        links.put('STOP')
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
        web_connection.put('STOP')

    for beaut_soup_object in iter(web_connection.get, 'STOP'):
        p_tags.append(beaut_soup_object.find_all('p'))
    for paragraphs in p_tags:
        bsoup_objects.append(BeautifulSoup(str(paragraphs)))
    for beautiful_soup_object in bsoup_objects:
        for link_tag in beautiful_soup_object.find_all('a'):
            extracted_urls.append(link_tag.get('href'))
    return extracted_urls

def create_bsoup_object(links, web_connection):

    for link in iter(links.get, 'STOP'):
        try:
            web_connection.put(BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link, timeout=3.05).content))
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
            #client couldn't connect to server or return data in time period specified in timeout parameter in requests.get()
            pass  
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            #in case of faulty url
            pass           
        except Exception, err:
            #catch regular errors
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            pass
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            pass
    return True
```

And when I run collect_links(urls), rather than getting a list of links, I get an empty list with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 266, in _feed
    send(obj)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
[]
```

I'm not sure what that's referring to. I read somewhere that Queues work best with simple objects. Does the size of the beautiful soup objects I'm storing in them have anything to do with this? I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Get rid of the `except … pass` clauses that are throwing away useful information. Put that information in this question. Don't ever use `except …: pass` it will always be wrong.

Comment: @msw what do you advice , because i use it to retrieve data from html, sometimes , the data isn't there because different pages is a few % different from another. I ended up with lots of except and pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects that you place on the queue need to be pickleable. Eg.

```
import pickle
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://httpbin.org').text)
print type(soup)
p = pickle.dumps(soup)
```

This code raises `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

Instead you could put the actual HTML text on the queue, and pass that through BeautifulSoup in the main thread. This will still improve performance as your application is likely to be I/O bound due to its networking component.

Do this in `create_bsoup_object()`:

```
web_connection.put(requests.get(link, timeout=3.05).text)
```

which will add the HTML onto the queue instead of the BeautifulSoup object. Then parse the HTML in the main process.

Alternatively parse and extract the URLs in the  child processes, and put the `extracted_urls` on the queue.